# What are the 0, 1 and 2 in three.js Face3

Tags: three.js

In [the three.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Face3) it says the following for creating a Face3

```
//create a triangular geometry
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -50, -50, 0 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  50, -50, 0 ) );
geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  50,  50, 0 ) );

//create a new face using vertices 0, 1, 2
var normal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ); //optional
var color = new THREE.Color( 0xffaa00 ); //optional
var materialIndex = 0; //optional
var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2, normal, color, materialIndex );
```

### What are the number `0, 1, 2` and how are they populated?

It literally says in the comment **create a face using vertices 0, 1, 2** but how are the numbers here:

```
var normal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ); //optional
                                ^  ^  ^
```

populated from the geometry above? I can't see where the above vertices are passed in.
And later on we have some more numbers. I imagine they could be the indexes from the `normal` argument in this function.

```
var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2, normal, color, materialIndex );
                            ^  ^  ^
```

The first one

```
var normal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ); //optional
```

– doesn't even pass the `geometry` variable through. And I'm also unsure of why the first one uses `0, 1, 0` and the second uses `0, 1, 2`

I'm new to three.js and having its hard to understand how everything works together.

Comment: These are indices of vectors from `vertices` array.

Comment: @prisoner849 How are they accessed... Is the `geometry.vertices` global?

Comment: "Face3: Triangular face used in Geometry. These are created automatically for all standard geometry types, however if you are building a custom geometry you will have to create them manually."  In the docs for `Geometry`, you will find a property called [`faces`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry.faces) which is an array of `Face3` objects, so each `Face3` references vertices (by index) in its parent `Geometry` object.

Comment: The line of the docs `geometry.faces.push( face );` should be self-explaining. The face becomes a part of the geometry object.

Comment: Honestly, if you're still new to three.js it might be better (and more clear to you) to look into creating [`BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry) instead. There are no "face" objects, just buffers (attributes) describing vertices (`bufgeo.attributes.position`, `bufgeo.attributes.normal`) and indices (`bufgeo.index`).

Comment: The numbers in `var normal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 )` have no direct relationship to the indices of the vertices, it is just creating a vector, The numbers in `THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2,` are referencing the vertex indices. AFAIK. I think the Djave is getting confused thinking both sets of numbers are referencing the same thing. The comment `//create a new face using vertices 0, 1, 2` would be better placed directly above `var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers `0,1,2` are called indices. Triangular geometry can be represented in two ways - indexed and "triangle soup".

Triangle soup requires no indices, it's just a collection of vertices.

```
const vertices = [
  vert0,
  vert1,
  vert2,
  vert0, //notice it's mentioned again
  vert3,
  vert1, //same here
]
```

These six vertices could describe two triangles. `vert0` and `vert1` are mentioned twice, but in the buffer they are expanded. So if you have some value like `[0,0,0]` and `[1,1,0]` you will repeat these numbers twice. This is called a triangle soup since every triangle is described on its own.

To save some memory we can describe the same geometry as such:

```
const vertices = [
  vert0,
  vert1,
  vert2,
  vert3
]
```

Notice that there is no duplication, instead of 6 vertices describing 2 triangles, we only provide 4. How do we get the same number of triangles? Using indices:

```
const indices= [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  0,
  3,
  1
]
```

We can now index into the 4 vertices without having to duplicate them.

Things get complicated when describing something like a cube. A triangle soup cube would have 36 vertices. An indexed one would not have 8 if that is the assumption, it would require 24. The diagonal of the face can be shared, so the same vertex can be mentioned twice. However, at the edges we need two distinct vertices to refer to two different normals. Even though the values of the vertices are the same, they have to be repeated in one buffer, so that the normal buffer, holding two unique entries can be addressed properly.